# Concordanza tra aggettivi e parentesi

Tags: grammar, adjectives, agreement

Dovendo scrivere:

> "le granulazioni aracnoidee (o villi aracnoidei)"

preferirei scrivere:

> "le granulazioni (o villi) aracnoidee"

ma a quel punto perderei la concordanza col sostantivo in parentesi.
Cosa si fa in questi casi? Esiste un'etichetta o semplicemente si aggira il problema scrivendo come nel primo blockquote?

Comment: Commento anziché rispondere perché è essenzialmente un'opinione personale. In generale io mi comporto in modo che il contenuto delle parentesi si possa omettere e la frase continui ad essere sensata, e perciò considererei accettabile anche la seconda. Ma in effetti stride un po' e quindi, a maggior ragione in presenza di termini tecnici, su cui il lettore potrebbe magari anche avere qualche dubbio circa il genere etc., andrei sul sicuro e ripeterei il tutto, come nel primo esempio.

Comment: Grazie per il commento, sono dello stesso parere.